# Insert indefinite amount of values into sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a list and `len(list)` is say `199` but it can increase during runtime at the same pace that the columns of my table will increase.

I want to INSERT these elements in a table in sqlite.

Code so far:

```
conn.execute('INSERT INTO Financial_data VALUES (?)',list)
```

I have read the docs and other s.o questions but I cannot place 199 question marks over there and even if I could, maybe after 20 seconds of running there will be 200 columns, what then?

***What I want to do is fill all the columns of a row with data***

Before the above code I have this, which inserts in a list elements for every header that exists in the sql database and if my other source has no value for one of the headers it appends a `None` value ***so I could be able to dump an entire row at once.***

```
if header in lista_header_tabel:
    lista_valori.append(valoare)
else:
    lista_valori.append(None)
```

This is happening because the insert part of the program is going really slow and I don't know why. I tried to include them inside a `conn.execute("begin")` and it improves performance but...

Shouldnt sqlite be able to handle sizes of say 20-50K rows with 200 columns? At this point I have better performance using shelve or json than using sqlite. 
Where am I going wrong?

Current working solution but slow after 2k rows:

```
conn.execute("begin")
    for celula in rand:
        if sheet_results.cell(row=1,column=celula.col_idx).value in lista_header_tabel and celula.value!=None:

                header_coloana=sheet_results.cell(row=1,column=celula.col_idx).value
                valoare_aferenta=str(celula.value).replace('"','^')
                nume_fara_ghilimele=str(rand[1].value).replace('"','^')
                query='UPDATE Financial_data SET "' + header_coloana + '" = "' + valoare_aferenta + '" WHERE `Company name`="' + nume_fara_ghilimele + '"'
                #print(query)
                conn.execute(query)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Simple: **Don't use a variable number of columns**. Use proper normalisation instead.

Comment: A SQL table is not suited to dynamic definition. SQL databases optimise for the number of columns being stable. Don't try to make them do otherwise. Use a `(id, key, value)` format instead, where `(id, key)` can be the primary key. You can then insert as many key-value pairs as needed for a given ID.

Comment: And if i have 199 columns to insert at once? I have to write 199 of (?,)?? @MartijnPieters

Comment: Also, your question seems to suggest that you're manually creating these `?` in the query string? Something like `placeholders = ['?' for item in the_list]` and then `"...VALUES ({})".format(', '.join(item for item in placeholders))` allows for this to be dynamic, but it's not a good idea to have a database setup like this.

Comment: @Mike: use `cursor.executemany()` to execute an `INSERT` statement repeatedly for a sequence of rows. And use `with connection:` to manage a transaction (the whole block under the `with` is all executed in one transaction and rolled back together if there was an exception).

Comment: @Mike: so for 199 column, use `cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO T VALUES(?, ?, ?)', [(id, key, value), (id, key, value), (id, key, value), ...])`.

Comment: Thx for the answers, i was very uncertain that these are real limitations of sql database... The problem is that my solution works fine but after 2k rows it slows down painfully- i'm editing now the question with my current working solution so u can see what i m talking about

Comment: @roganjosh Thx for the comment, i ll try and see how that works. Why isnt it a good idea? it seems to me that this is the only solution to make it so.

Comment: @Mike my original understanding is that you somehow have an ever-expanding number of columns going into the DB. If you simply want to get your insert statement to match the length of the record you are trying to insert, then it's a perfectly valid method to not have to type the `?` by hand.

Comment: @roganjosh Program parses some excel files and adds new columns if any, there might be a new column once at 10 files or 1k rows but it s limited, it s not ever-expanding, only a bit dynamic. Thx again for the suggestion, i m new to pyth and would have struggled a bit to get there syntax-wise :)

Comment: BTW, inserting 100000 rows (of only 2 columns) in a sqlite3 table takes no more than 13 seconds. Build a generator from your excel sheet and use it to feed an `executemany`, it should speed up insertion. Anyway, writing should be faster with json than with sqlite, but extraction with sql is much more powerful...