# Difficulty opening sql database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

#### what i m trying to do is point to a relative path inside my django app.

- I do have to mention that test.py, forms.py and search.py are all in the same directory

I have 2 .py files, the first one is this:

***Test.py***

```
import os
import sqlite3

docs= os.path.abspath('..').rsplit("\\",1)[0]
datab=(docs+ "\\BMS\\Database\\Database.db")
datab.encode('unicode-escape')
conn=sqlite3.connect(datab)
```

This works fine, while i have the exact same code in search.py, inside a class which i import in forms.py which is part of ***django***

**search.py**

```
import sqlite3
import os


class SearchBy(object):

    docs= os.path.abspath('..').rsplit("\\",1)[0]
    datab=(docs+ "\\BMS\\Database\\Database.db")
    datab.encode('unicode-escape')
    conn=sqlite3.connect(datab)

    def get_countries(self):
        do something
```

and finally **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
import sqlite3
from .search import SearchBy


class searchForm(forms.Form):

    search_class=SearchBy()
    lista_tari=get_countries()


    country=forms.ChoiceField(choices=lista_tari, widget=forms.Select(), initial=0,required=True)
```

I simply cannot uderstand why i am given this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Under the circumstances that in the other file everything works fine.

Comment: Why are you opening the sqlite file explicitly? Why not define it as a database in the Django settings?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have a different script that handles that particular database. the user uploads some files and the information gets extracted into the database, i have a variable number of columns there and it would be so much work to make a django model for it. See this for one of the issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761312/insert-indefinite-amount-of-values-into-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Check your file architecture , when you include a .py file in python, the path in included file , is imported as it is.
Meaning if they arent in the same folder , the path is different between the 2

Comment: they are in the same folder, i ran print(datab) in search.py and it points to the right directory